# Erro ao compilar no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Fiz um primeiro projeto no android studio, mas ao compilar ele gera os seguintes erros:

> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>   Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

Me parece que é erro em alguma biblioteca, provavelmente de versões diferentes do Android, só que não consegui trocar. Se puder ajudar, agradeço.

Edit: achei o q era. Um erro de compatibilidade de versoes. So fui em build.gradle e alterei o compileSdkVerision e o targetSdkVersion para 23

Answer (score 2):

Veja [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name) no Stackoverflow em inglês.

Pode ser uma incompatibilidade entre a versão da sua SDK compilada e a versão da "support library". Verifique se ambas estão iguais e caso não estejam, altere uma delas.

Answer (score 1):

Procure no xml de algum layout os atributos:
`android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse`
`android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored`

Remova eles.